# How to explain the following code about path-dependent type and polymorphism

Tags: scala

I ran the following code as a scala script,then got the a compiler
error

```
class Food
abstract class Animal {
  type SuitableFood <: Food
  def eat(food: SuitableFood)
}

class Grass extends Food
class Cow extends Animal {
  type SuitableFood = Grass
  override def eat(food: Grass) {}
}

val bessy:Animal = new Cow
bessy eat (new Grass)
```

then I got the a compiler error

```
script.scala:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : this.Grass
 required: this.bessy.SuitableFood
bessy eat (new Grass)
           ^
```

Next,I change some code as following:

```
val bessy = new Cow
class Fish extends Food
bessy eat (new Fish)
```

I got another error

```
script.scala:18: error: type mismatch;
 found   : this.Fish
 required: this.Grass
bessy eat (new Fish)
           ^
```

The required type is different in the two cases,how to explain it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL; DR** when you upcast to `Animal`, you strip compiler of knowledge that `bessy.SuitableFood = Grass`

---

For the purpose of explanation I've taken a liberty to slightly modify your definition of `Cow`:

```
class Cow extends Animal with Food {
  type SuitableFood = Grass
  def moo() = "moo"
  override def eat(food: SuitableFood) = println(moo())
}
```

If you're working with `Cow` specifically, there's no question to what `SuitableFood` is, so the compiler can give you a fairly helpful error message.

```
val bessy = new Cow  // same as val bessy: Cow = new Cow
bessy.eat(new Grass) // <- totally valid
println(bessy.moo()) // <- and again
bessy.eat(new Fish)  // <- does not typecheck
```

Notice that type inference gave you the most precise info available.

When you upcast to the parent type (`Animal`), the knowledge of `bessy` being a `Cow` is lost to the compiler, and so is the knowledge of `bessy.SuitableFood` being `Grass`. It can only tell you as much as it knows, so the error message is different

```
val bessyAsAnimal: Animal = bessy
//bessyAsAnimal.eat(new Grass) // <- won't typecheck, your problem
```

Actually, at this point you will not be able to call `bessyAsAnimal.eat(...)` at all (without type casts, which we don't consider). Let's take a look at one of the ways to retain that ability: a refinement type:

```
val bessyRefinedAnimal: Animal { type SuitableFood = Grass } = bessy
bessyRefinedAnimal.eat(new Grass) // <- valid again
//bessyRefinedAnimal.moo() // <- won't compile
```

This is kinda cumbersome, but works. We don't know that bessyRefinedAnimal is a `Cow`, so we cannot call `Cow`-specific methods on it anymore. Still, you can feed it, and it will only accept `Grass`

So if all you know is `Animal`, there's no way to feed it. Try that:

```
def doSomethingWithAnimal(animal: Animal) = {
  // without casts, no call to animal.feed(...) will compile
  // tho if Animal has methods not dependent on SuitableFood,
  // those could be used
}
```

So, what's the point of all this? Well, you are still able to feed an animal without knowing which **particular** food it likes, be it `Grass` or `Fish`, but knowing that it is the **right** one:

```
def feedAnimal(animal: Animal)(food: animal.SuitableFood) = {
  println("It's dinner time!")
  animal.eat(food)
  // animal.eat(new Grass) will not work
  // nor will animal.moo()
  // we can only use argument here
  println("Feeding routine complete")
}
```

And we will be able to use this method from the places where knowledge of concrete types still exists:

```
feedAnimal(bessy)(new Grass) // prints the lines
// feedAnimal(bessy)(new Fish) // won't typecheck
```

Comment: what bothers me a bit in the `Cow` declaration is that `SuitableFood` type is instantiated to be `Grass` but in the `eat` method definition this type is not used. Why `Grass` is provided in the method signature instead of `SuitableFood` ?

Comment: @AlexanderArendar that does not matter at all (compiler figures out this is valid, otherwise it would give a compile error), and OP made it that way. I edited it to be `SuitableFood` , and rest of the code works exactly the same, so might just leave it there. Tho often it's more convenient / readable to work with concrete types.

Comment: yeah, my point was that if one introduces a type alias in the class then one should probably use this type alias. Otherwise there is no difference as you stated.

Comment: @AlexanderArendar Because you aren't always working inside the class. When you just have an `Animal`, you use `SuitableFood` (and that's what you have to pass to `eat`).

Answer (score 2):

I can't explain exact mechanics of these compiler errors but I do believe for such problems one needs to use type parameterization.
The best way I could model this to work in more or less clean way is this:

```
object Amimals {

  def main(args:Array[String]):Unit = {

    trait Food
    trait Animal[AllowedFood<:Food]{
      def eat(food:AllowedFood)
    }

    class Grass extends Food
    class Meat extends Food

    class Herbivore[AllowedFood<:Grass] extends Animal[AllowedFood] {
      override def eat(food:AllowedFood) = {println("I can eat only grass")}
    }

    class Cow extends Herbivore[Grass]


    val bessy = new Cow
    bessy eat new Grass
    //bessy eat new Meat
  }
}
```

This way you can instantiate the `Cow` instance and it will know that it can only it `Grass` or `Grass` derivatives.
If you try to uncomment last line it will produce compilation error:

```
Error:(22, 15) type mismatch;
 found   : Meat
 required: Grass
    bessy eat new Meat
              ^
```

Comment: This completely defeats the purpose: `bessy eat bessy` and `bessy eat new java.net.URL("http://example.com")` are now valid in your example

Comment: sorry, you are right. That was meant to be `eat[T<:SuitableFood](food:T)` but it wont compile either.

Comment: "I do believe for such problems one needs to use type parameterization" No, it's a possible approach, but not the only one. Type members allow some things which are hard/inconvenient with type parameters and vice versa.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov, I hope so and hope one day I will be able to clearly see such cases :)